# Project Structure of Domain Driven Design in maven Java Spring-Boot

Tags: java, architecture, domain-driven-design, spring

My team is in dilemma, we have an existing maven spring-boot Java8 project with following onion architechture.

```
controller --> service --> dao --> jpa repositories
                            |  --> filesystem
                            |  --> jdbc template
```

Dao earlier using jdbc template and jpa, so it had more than one way of accessing data via many strategies. But as we are moving forward old `JDBC Template` to new `JPA Repositories`, we are planning to remove `dao layer` and injecting repositories directly into service.

So new architecture might look something like this:-

```
controller --> service --> jpa repositories
```

I have a few concerns now:-

1. How good is this idea of removing an abstraction layer of dao?
2. Does this architecture  have anything to do with Domain Driven Design?
3. We have around 20 Dao Classes and more than 50 JpaRepositories and entities,so I want to consider human-hours into this refactoring, will it be huge or just nominal?
4. Will we make our service classes a `GOD Class` which will have business logic and operations related to data access?

Comment: How is this possible? A DDD app with no **domain** module/package?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your new architecture is also not derive from Domain Driven Design. Of course in context of tactical patterns (as strategy patterns scope go beyond the code).

In Domain Driven Design you have plenty useful building blocks which can help you with managing accidental complexity of your system. But before you start tot apply them you need to answer very important question

### Do I really need DDD building blocks in my system/module?

Answer should be yes if your system has rich business logic not just simple CRUD (it is of course simplification, you have a lot of articles about it).
Note: I am referring to tactical part of DDD. I really believe in using DDD strategic patterns event for CRUD-like applications (e.g. ubiquitous language).

OK, as the topic is very broad I will give you few simple steps you can weave into your system (it is more less concept of hexagonal architecture).

**1)** Split your application into modules. They would be more less you **Bounded Contexts**. How to do it in Java? Use **packages** - they are really powerful.

So you will have e.g `com.mycompany.mysystem.order, com.mycompany.mysystem.invoice`

**2)** Your **Bounded Context** will be built upon some **Aggregate**. Aggregate is everything which should be processed in one transaction. Root of your aggregate can be represented as your JPA Entity.

```
@Entity
class Order {
@Id
String id;
List<Product> products;

void addProductToOrder(...) {
... some business logic
}

Money calculateDiscount(...) {
... some business logic
}
```

Your Entities should be Rich Entities - contains behavior, not just preserve structure. You can also use concepts like immutable Value Objects.

**3)** Create repository for your aggregate but only for your business part - so that you can save your aggregate and retrieve it. You can use e.g. Spring Data.

**4)** Create Facade to collect methods needed to perform some action. You can keep validation there but remember that behavior itself should be kept inside aggregate.

**5)** You can use also other patterns like Factory, Strategy, Observer, etc. All OO patterns fit well into DDD.

**6)** Keep all these classes in domain package, e.g.

```
com.mycompany.mysystem.order.domain
- Order.java
- OrderRepository.java
- OrderFacade.java
- OrderFactory.java
```

Only OrderFacade should be public. Other classes should have package scope.

**7)** Now, you can create another subpackage - infrastructure. You will keep Spring configuration there, Rest Controller, etc. Everything not related to the domain.

```
com.mycompany.mysystem.order.domain
    - Order.java
    - OrderRepository.java
    - OrderFacade.java
    - OrderFactory.java
com.mycompany.mysystem.order.infrastructure
    - OrderCommandController.java
    - OrderConfiguration.java
```

**8)** There is one very powerful concept used often with DDD. It is called **CQRS**. You can read about it, there are many sources. I will give you one tip how you can add it to above example.

Do you have situations when you need to retrieve something from database on million ways? Yeah, everybody does.

So according to CQRS you can split your commands/business operations and queries. Following our example, create new subpackage

```
com.mycompany.mysystem.order.query
```

Inside you can create Entity called OrderQuery and point it to the same table in database (or use projection in more advanced cases). You can now create new repository (Spring Data) and use it with OrderQuery. In infrastructure subpackage add new controller OrderQueryController.

These steps are obviously just a skeleton and contains many simplifications. It should be enough to start and guide you in good direction.

Comment: In step 6, where would be the domain service ? As far as I understand, you used the facade as domain service and would return DTOs to upper layers, am I correct ?

Comment: Some controversy could be found in this good article: https://codeforfunandmoney.wordpress.com/2016/07/13/domain-driven-design-and-package-organization/